# Use of bsxfun with singleton expansion with matrixes of three dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, bsxfun

I'm using `bsxfun` to vectorize an operation with singleton expansion between matrixes of sizes:

```
MS: (nms, nls)
KS: (nks, nls)
```

The operation is the sum of the absolute differences between each value `MS(m,l)` with `m` in `1:nms` and `l` in `1:nls`, and every `KS(k,l)` with `k` in `1:nks`.

I achieve this through the code:

```
[~, nls] = size(MS);
MS = reshape(MS',1,nls,[]);
R = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,MS,KS)));
```

`R` is of size `(nls, nms)`.

I want to generalize this operation to a list of samples, so the new sizes will be:

```
MS: (nxs, nls, nms)
KS: (nxs, nls, nks)
```

This can be achieved easily with a for loop that executes the first piece of code for each 2 dimensional matrixes, but I suspect that performance may be much better by generalizing the previous code by adding a new dimension.

`R` has would be of size: `(nxs, nls, nms)`

I have tried to reshape `MS` to 4 dimensions with no success. Could this be done with reshaping and `bsxfun`?

Comment: It can be done, but your description of dimensions is a bit unclear to me. Can you give a small example? Or explain how the new sizes are related to the old sizes?

Comment: I added an answer based on `bsxfun` and `permute`. If your dimensions are huge and performance is important, it might be faster to `permute` the summing index to be in the first place, so that the `sum`mation acts on contiguous blocks of memory.

Comment: Do you mean permuting on MS?

Comment: @jruizaranguren I mean using `sum(permute(abs(bsxfun(...)),[4 1 2 3]),1)` where `...` is the same as before. Or something similar, I'm not sure what's *most* efficient.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrasDeak, I will test it.

Comment: @jruizaranguren it turns out that my naive idea was too naive... I updated my answer with a possibly working speed-up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need this:

```
% generate small dummy data
nxs = 2;
nls = 3;
nms = 4;
nks = 5;
MS = rand(nxs, nls, nms);
KS = rand(nxs, nls, nks);

R = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,MS,permute(KS,[1,2,4,3]))),4)
```

This will produce a matrix of size `[2,3,4]`, i.e. `[nxs,nls,nms]`. Each element `[k1,k2,k3]` will correspond to

```
R(k1,k2,k3) == sum_k abs(MS(k1,k2,k3) - KS(k1,k2,k))
```

For instance, in my random run

```
R(2,1,3)

ans =

   1.255765020150647

>> sum(abs(MS(2,1,3)-KS(2,1,:)))

ans =

   1.255765020150647
```

The trick is to introduce singleton dimensions with `permute`: `permute(KS,[1,2,4,3])` is of size `[nxs,nls,1,nks]`, while `MS` of size `[nxs,nls,nms]` is implicitly also of size `[nxs,nls,nms,1]`: every array in MATLAB is assumed to possess a countably infinite number of trailing singleton dimensions. From here it's easy to see how you can `bsxfun` together arrays of size `[nxs,nls,nms,1]` and `[nxs,nls,1,nks]`, respectively, to obtain one with size `[nxs,nls,nms,nks]`. Summing along dimension 4 seals the deal.

---

I noted in a comment, that it might be faster to `permute` the summing index to be in the first place. Turns out that this by itself makes the code run *slower*. However, by reshaping the arrays to have decreasing dimension sizes, the overall performance increases (due to optimal memory access). Compare this:

```
% generate larger dummy data
nxs = 20;
nls = 30;
nms = 40;
nks = 500;
MS = rand(nxs, nls, nms);
KS = rand(nxs, nls, nks);

MS2 = permute(MS,[4 3 2 1]);
KS2 = permute(KS,[3 4 2 1]);
R3 = permute(squeeze(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,MS2,KS2)),1)),[3 2 1]);
```

What I did was put the summing `nks` dimension into first place, and order the rest of the dimensions in decreasing order. This could be done automatically, I just didn't want to overcomplicate the example. In your use case you'll probably know the magnitude of the dimensions anyway.

Runtimes with the above two codes: 0.07028 s for the original, 0.051162 s for the reordered one (best out of 5). Larger examples don't fit into memory for me now, unfortunately.

Comment: `4D` permute! Nice!!

Comment: @Divakar thank you!:) I hope to reach your 6D level one day;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I have been able to reproduce the same behavior. In my case, the dimensions hold that nxs >>  nks > nms ~ nls, so I can arrange it beforehand. Nevertheless, I do not get a noticeable improvement once nxs is in the first place.

Comment: @jruizaranguren Did you try what I wrote, that *the summing dimension is first*, and *the rest* are in decreasing order? Either that, or "`nxs` first", or the unpermuted original version should be fastest.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, sorry, I read too fast. With matrixes of size (10000, 10, 100) I get better performance with the original code.

Comment: @jruizaranguren well that's also an answer:) I wasn't sure either way, but it was worth checking out. Thanks for the feedback!